# QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method

Tags: c++, qt

I get the below error when I use GET of QNetworkAccessManager:

```
void ItemObjectAPI::getRequest (const QString &urlString)
{
    QUrl url (BaseUrl + urlString);
    QNetworkRequest req (url);
    m_NetworkAccessManager.get (req);
}
```

1. QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
2. QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
3. QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
4. QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
5. (Internal error: pc 0x1 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
6. (Internal error: pc 0x0 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
7. Debugging has finished

Im using qt5, windows 8 32 bit OS pc. How to resolve this?

Comment: Which openssl version are you using?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I have not installed any specific openssl in my pc. If I am building this application for android device, do I have to install it on android device too?